# Multiple t tests with Bonferroni correction instead of Anova and posthoc?

Tags: t-test, heteroscedasticity, bonferroni

I have a set of 6 experiments that were all performed at the same time. 
This consists of 3 genotypes (A, B, C) , each under two conditions (1 and 2) with a single measurement variable.

I just want to check if there is a difference between each condition for each genotype. 
ie.

```
Is A1 significantly different from A2 
Is B1 significantly different from B2 
Is C1 significantly different from C2
```

In addition for each genotype the conditions are heteroscedastic, n=30 and roughly the same for each sample. 
My question is how do I analyze this data. My idea was to use an ANOVA and then multiple comparisons x3 Welch T-tests with a Bonferroni adjustment on the p-values. Is this a valid approach?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Why are you avoiding ANOVA?